# bash: ./configure :No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I want to install siesta-4.1-b4 in ubuntu 18.04.
I run following command:

```
sudo tar -xzvf siesta-4.0.1.tar.gz
cd siesta-4.0.1/Obj
sh ../Src/obj_setup.sh
cd ../Src
./configure
```

I have this error

```
./configure: No such file or directory
```

Could you help me to fixed the problem, please?

Comment: try running `make install`

Answer (score 0):

The
[documentation](https://departments.icmab.es/leem/siesta/Documentation/Manuals/siesta-4.0.pdf)
says only this:

```
cd siesta-4.0.1/Obj
sh ../Src/obj_setup.sh
make
```

And the same for the utility programs in `Util`.

Remark: The latest version currently seems to be
[siesta-4.1-b4.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/siesta).